# How to change path of log files?

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to store my log files in usb so that they can be used  for further analysis. I have mounted usb on my raspian os.I need python code so that log files can be stored in usb.

Comment: First, do you understand how accessing usb devices works in Debian ? I don't think there's already a library for doing this, so you must really understand it before! ;)

Comment: i have mounted the usb device....usb can be accessed through the file manager as well as from the terminal.....i want to set path of log files through python program....

Answer (score 0):

When your device is mounted, you must access it through `/mnt/name` where the device is mounted under `name`. Then, you'll find there everything that is on your device. To write log file, for example, you coul do:

```
with open("/mnt/sdb1", 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write('Start logging\n')
    # Write logging data
```